# Disable required attribute on one radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 radio buttons in a bootstrap modal and I want only 2 of them to be required in order to submit the form. I created a requiredCheck() function that's using a jQuery implementation so I'd rather not use this. What is the best way to disable the required attribute for one radio button, when using AngularJS?

### HTML

```
<form name="jawn">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Jawn</h3>
      </div><!-- /modal-header -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="item in items">
            <label for="optionsRadios">
                <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.data.status" name="optionsRadios" ng-value="item.id" required/ ng-click="requiredCheck()"> {{item.name}}
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <h4>Comment</h4>
        <textarea ng-class="{error: thing.comment.$dirty && thing.comment.$invalid}" type="text" rows="3" cols="64" ng-model="data.comment" ng-minlength="4" ng-required></textarea>
        <span class="error" ng-show="thing.comment.$error.required">required</span>
      </div><!-- /modal-body-->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="ok()" ng-disabled="thing.$invalid">Part Jawn</button>
        <button type="button" ng-click="cancel()" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

### JavaScript

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('ModalController', function($scope, $modalInstance, $timeout) {
  'use strict';

  $scope.item = 0;

  $scope.items = [
    "Zero": 0,
    "Uno": 1,
    "Dos": 2
  ];

  $scope.requiredCheck = function () {
    var $btnWarning = $('.btn-warning');
    var $textarea = $('textarea');
    $timeout(function() {
      if($scope.data.status === item.Dos) {
        $btnWarning.removeAttr('disabled');
        $textarea.removeAttr('required');
      } else if ($scope.data.status === 3) {
        $btnWarning.prop('disabled',true);
        $textarea.prop('required', true);
      } else if ($scope.data.status === 3) {
        $btnWarning.prop('disabled',true);
        $textarea.prop('required', true);
      }
    },100);
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {

  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    $modalInstance.close();
  };

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [angualrjs](/questions/tagged/angualrjs) approach. As you have already specified `ngRequired` set `true`/`false` from controller.

From [DOCs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input)

> ngRequired: Sets required attribute if set to true

*HTML*

```
<textarea ng-model="data.comment" ng-required="textRequired"></textarea>
```

*Script*

```
$scope.requiredCheck = function () {
    if(condition){
        $scope.textRequired = false;
    }else{
        $scope.textRequired = true;
    }       
};
```

*Note: I have simplified the answer*

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much Satpal. I had it in my head that the ng-required attribute wasn't allowed to have a value. My mistake and thanks again.